# Invalid CSRF token. Send the form again. Adminer

Tags: adminer

I am getting this error on export of my database in adminer.
Error: **Invalid CSRF token. Send the form again. If you did not send this request from Adminer then close this page.** Need Help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem for me was that the session cookie had the `secure` flag, while I was accessing adminer via http only (not https).

---

Our nginx configuration had

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
```

which I had to remove.

Answer (score 13):

Try this!

```
chgrp nginx /var/lib/php/session
```

The problem may cause by session save path not writable. I have faced the same problem and I fixed it by above command. I use nginx but if you use another web server, just change it. Hope this helps!

Comment: This did the trick for me. Seems that many answers here point into that direction.

Answer (score 6):

Check that `/var/lib/php/session` exists and that `nginx` can write to it.

Answer (score 4):

Your session should contain a CSRF token to prevent a CSRF attack. This message means that you either have no token stored or your token is not the same as that generated by your server.
I assume that you don't have a writable path configured in your php.ini where you can store the session. Please check if you have set **session.save_path in php.ini** to a writable path.

Answer (score 4):

Find **session.save_path** in phpinfo (/var/lib/php/session for Centos) and change the mode:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session
```

done!

Answer (score 3):

What setup are you using? I had this happen with nginx + php-fpm, and after I did a diff of `php.ini` of one machine where adminer worked and one where it didn't, and found out that I needed to blank out the value for `session.cookie_domain`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a phpinfo.php file

   `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`
2. Find real session save path

   `/var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session`

   [image]
3. Change directory permission

   `chmod -R 0777 /var/opt/remi/php72/lib/php/session`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens on previous PHP versions, which is not very important.
You can refresh the page or reopen it, this will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me an hour ago.
Check you have enough space in /var.
I cleaned it and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

https://sourceforge.net/p/adminer/bugs-and-features/174/#429b : Yes this problem is caused by session savepath not being writable, add this line to the top of your file, will work if your host allows it

ini_set( 'session.save_path', 'path/to/writable/directory/' );

Answer (score 0):

Check if your filesystem is not full.

```
df - kh
```

It can be a explanation of not be able to write on it.